# Simple Odata Client to consume Odata with Authentication not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, simple.odata.client

I m new to Simple.Odata.client. I had a problem to access the Odata Service with below code. The below code return null. but Postman return with result.

1. suspected Problem : How to pass a url string with '1000' &format=json
2. Is the below Simple odata client setup correctly?
3. There is no UrlBase in Simple Odata client, but there is BAseUri
4. Is this ODataClientSettings working??

   var settings = new Simple.OData.Client.ODataClientSettings();

   settings.BaseUri = new Uri("https://..../UoM?$filter=wer eg '1000' &format=json");

   settings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1", "usrpwd");
           var client = new ODataClient(settings);

please help

Thanks

Comment: Maybe put a `WebUtility.UrlEncode();` around it?

Comment: I am not sure I got it right. I got invalid url. here how I use your suggestion. This is the url : strUrl = "https://..../HandlingUnitSet?$filter=Werk eq '1000'&$format=json"  
settings.BaseUri = new Uri(WebUtility.UrlEncode(strUrl));  Please advise how to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password); //you can use the override with the domain too.
var settings = new ODataClientSettings(baseUrl, credentials) //baseUrl is a string.
        {
            IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true,
            OnTrace = (x, y) => Debug.WriteLine(x, y),
            PayloadFormat = ODataPayloadFormat.Json, //here is where you specify the format
            IgnoreUnmappedProperties = true,
            RenewHttpConnection = true,
            TraceFilter = ODataTrace.All,
            PreferredUpdateMethod = ODataUpdateMethod.Merge
        };
var client = new ODataClient(settings);
```

Your baseUrl should not contain all those OData tags but the endpoint of your service like https://myservice.mysite.com/api.svc. Then as you use the [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client) the resource url will be automatically completed.

Please, take a look at the [OData](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/) standard to figure out how it works and see the Simple.OData.Client repo's examples to better understand how to use it.

To better understand how to use the Windows Authentication you can check [Authentication and Authorization with Windows Accounts](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/authentication-and-authorization-with-windows-accounts-in-asp-net/) and [how to access website with Windows credential](https://rocky1978.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/c-how-to-access-website-with-windows-credential-ntlm/)

Hope this help.